# SSL connection to MySQL using SQLAlchemy

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, ssl-certificate

I have a flask application which runs inside a Docker container.
The application writes data to MySQL db.
The MySQL DB has ssl enable, require_secure_transport = ON.

when I am trying to use the application in order to write data to the mysql db I am getting error since the flask application doesn't has SSL enable.
(When I disable the SSL on the MySQL server everything works.)

The MySQL DB is hosted on Azure and I downloaded the certificate.
I got a file named: DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem

I asked ChatGBT how ot connect to the DB using the ceritifcate and generate this code:
I tried to connect to the db using the SSL certificate using Jupiter notebbok using this code and I got an error:
cert.serial_number

what I am missing?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
# Configure the SSL parameters- path to the .pem file
ssl_args = {
             "ssl": {
                      "cert": "/Users/talcohen/Downloads/DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem"  
                     }
           }

# Create the database engine
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://user:password@host:port/db_name", connect_args=ssl_args)


# Establish a connection
connection = engine.connect()

# Perform database operations
# ...

# Close the connection
connection.close()
```